# Adding look and feel into java application

Tags: java, look-and-feel, netbeans6.5

I am working with the **NetBeans 6.5 IDE**.

I downloaded a look and feel jar file and added it NetBeans by palette manager.

How do I use it in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your reply.
By using the below code we can get all look and feel class names.

```
UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] lookAndFeelInfos = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    for (int i = 0; i < lookAndFeelInfos.length; i++) {
        UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lookAndFeelInfo = lookAndFeelInfos[i];

        //
        // Get the name of the look and feel
        //
        String name = lookAndFeelInfo.getName();
        System.out.println("name = " + name);

        //
        // Get the implementation class for the look and feel
        //
        String className = lookAndFeelInfo.getClassName();
        System.out.println("className = " + className);
    }
```

Comment: This will display the all installed look and feels.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this Sun tutorial about [setting the L&F in Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

> You can change the L&F with `setLookAndFeel` even after the program's GUI is visible.
>   To make existing components reflect the new L&F, invoke the `SwingUtilities` `updateComponentTreeUI` method once per top-level container.
>   Then you might wish to resize each top-level container to reflect the new sizes of its contained components. For example:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to get InfName for a look and feel. We have windows classic ( I am using windows OS) theme in NetBeans. whats the InfName for that.